# PPL EASA(A) exam cross-country flight altitude

Tags: ppl

I need find explanation for EASA PPL(A) question. According to the Boeing Courseware correct answer is **"a"**, but I can't find explanations in course materials neither in SERA or German AIP (questions are Germany specific).

**Provided that no other regulations or requirements demand a lower or higher altitude, the Minimum Safe Altitude for cross-country flights with powered aircraft is at least:**

```
a) 600 m AMSL 
b) 150 m above ground or water  
c) 300 m above ground or water
d) 600 m above ground or water
```

From my perspective **cross-country flight** is keyword there, and I can't find clear definition other than "flight in vicinity of aerodrome where a pilot don't need to observe traffic pattern traffic".

Please advice.

Comment: Did you check the [SERA](https://www.easa.europa.eu/sites/default/files/dfu/Easy%20Access%20Rules%20for%20Standardised%20European%20Rules%20of%20the%20Air%20%28SERA%29%20%28Revision%20from%20November%202021%29%20%28PDF%29.pdf) for minimum altitude or heights? What does it say and how does that not answer your question?